# twitter4j => AndroidRuntime(446): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to use twitter4j for my app to connect and post to twitter. I am following [this tutorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/). I have downloaded the example project from [here](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample) and try to run it on `android 2.3.3`. I am sure that i have modified `Constants.java` file correctly according to my twitter developer website. In `TwitterUtils.java` i have enter `OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` also. but after running it, i got following error messages :

```
> E/dalvikvm(374): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated

>W/dalvikvm(374): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;

>D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010

>D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: dead code 0x0012-002f in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;.isAuthenticated (Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;)Z

>E/dalvikvm(374): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.sendTweet

>W/dalvikvm(374): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;

>D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010

>D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: dead code 0x0012-002b in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;.sendTweet (Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;Ljava/lang/String;)V

>D/AndroidRuntime(374): Shutting down VM

>W/dalvikvm(374): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

>E/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:18)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.AndroidTwitterSample.updateLoginStatus(AndroidTwitterSample.java:72)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.AndroidTwitterSample.onResume(AndroidTwitterSample.java:68)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

>E/AndroidRuntime(374):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

am not sure if i am wrong, in Constant.java, i haven't change anything in

```
public static final String REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

public static final String ACCESS_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";

public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";

public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
```

I have tried changing `"callback"` with `"http://www.MyWebsite.com"`
Please advice how can I correct these problems.

Comment: have you updates your adt to ADT 17?

Comment: did you mean API level? .... i have it updated to API level 17 already, please let me know if you mean different thing. I am really new to android and java.

Comment: then what is your library folder name..it must be `libs` if you have kept it lib please change it to `libs` and then check

Comment: hey its work now!!! thank you so much Frankenstein. I can't believe i have spend almost 2 days for such small issues. you save me. Thanks.

Comment: okay..cause u didn't know..now you know :)

Comment: Can you shed more light on how to change twitter account? and i don't see any twitter permission page pop-up, is it normal? i have tried "Clear Credentials", still am logged-in.

Comment: I suggest ask it as separate Question or update the above Question..and write your problem in detail..

Comment: And also would like to tell you,AFAIK there is no way..you will get logged out from twitter using Twitter4j you just remove the SharedPreference which stored auth_token when press Logout button

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to change your Folder name from `lib` to `libs` as you have updated ADT 17.

Checkout this **[Article](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)** for in detail information on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is using ADT 18, I did not have a lib folder at all, I was using Project, Properties, Java Build Path, Libraries tab exclusively. To resolve this issue, I created a libs folder within my project, copied my external jars to this folder, and then removed the references in the Libraries tab. The project rebuilt and worked!