# Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper'?

Tags: android, jar, jackson

I am using jackson json parser, i've added "jackson-all-1.9.3.jar", when i declare

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;
```

The compiler recognize it but when i run my application on the emulator i get this error.

```
04-16 16:27:13.037: I/System.out(435): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-16 16:27:13.245: I/System.out(435): debugger has settled (1417)
04-16 16:27:13.734: E/dalvikvm(435): Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method com.test.weather.GetweatherInfo.<init>
04-16 16:27:13.734: W/dalvikvm(435): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 45 (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;) in Lcom/test/weather/GetweatherInfo
```

What should i do to fix it thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005206/twitter4j-androidruntime446-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-twitter4j-http/10007966#10007966 might be the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your Folder name from `lib` to `libs` as you have updated `ADT 17`.

Checkout this **[Article](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)** for in detail information on this topic.

Comment: I am still getting this error my folder name is libs from beginning

Comment: Ok i figured out, had to copy jar files to libs folder. Thanks!