# I get an error when I run the apk but not from the Android Studio

Tags: android

When I compile my apk I get an error when 'run' the apk, this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        
ComponentInfo{com.robsie.quiz/com.robsie.quiz.SplashActivity}:    
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5202)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating     
class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1885)
at com.robsie.quiz.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5108)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     
"android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.robsie.quiz-1.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
... 21 more
```

But when I open it from Android Studio, I do not get none if first 'Rebuild Project' and then 'Run' .. if only I 'run' I get this error ..

```
java: can not find symbol
symbol: Variable layout
location: class com.robsie.quiz.R
```

Im using CirclePageIndicator.. And this is my 'build.gradle'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':C::Users:shekel:Desktop:WorkSpace:library')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 11
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error states:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
```

Your gradle build config shows it as a dependency, but you may want to check where your module points to path-wise for the support library.

It's quite possible that Android Studio is failing to detect that your support library is unavailable and thusly you're able to compile, but see the application fail.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have not used the Android Studio, but for me it looks like a known bug of ADT, where you have to explicitly mark external libraries to be exported, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910/could-not-find-class-xxx-referenced-from-method-xxx-yyy/14770317#14770317) shows how it works in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message.

In order to build activity with actionbar with swipable tabs (ViewPager)

What I did was: update to latest Android Version (Current 0.4.4)

And it the Open new project wizard, select Navigation Type:

Action bar Tabs (with ViewPager) as below

[image]