# Could not find class X referenced from method X.<init>

Tags: android

I came across this strange problem while testing my app on a Galaxy S III. It works fine on other devices.

The subject class goes like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Service {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

[Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910/could-not-find-class-xxx-referenced-from-method-xxx-yyy) have had the same problem and it seems to be related to the built of the source code. However, I don't know how to solve this on Android Studio.

---

***SOLVED***

It appears that the cause of the problem where the **camera2 APIs** which were used in that class. Those APIs target **Lollipop** and above and for that reason the app was crashing trying to resolve the imports,even if at runtime I wasn't using any unavailable method (checking the build version of the device).

I'm not sure about the reason of this, but anyway moving the Camera2 implementation to another class fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **build.gradle** file.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
```

}

This should be the way sdk version should be defined, for further clarification please refer to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html