# Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter'

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have ,in a fragment, a method call who open an AlertDialog when an user tap on an button, in that dialog I would like to show a Spinner with countries ( Spain, Italy, French....)

My code for the spinner is the following:

```
RestCountries restCountries = new RestCountries();
    List<RestCountries.Datum>  countries = restCountries.data;
    String mCities ="";
    ArrayList<String> citiesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(RestCountries.Datum data : countries){
        mCities = data.name;
        citiesArrayList.add(mCities);
    }

    ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  citiesArrayList );
    mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

The spinner is showed emphy after the dialog is opened.

On the logcat I get

> ```
> Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced
> from method
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
> ```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong

Comment: are you using a device or an emulator?

Comment: which version does it use? API 23/ Marshmallow?

Comment: Yes it is correct API 23/ Marshmallow

Comment: according to [this link, especially inner class DropDownAdapter]
(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/080abff/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.java) 
the error happens while the constructor for the DropDownAdapter is executed ('IS_AT_LEAST_M' is true for your device). BUT then the runtime should be able to find 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter' on a Marshmallow device. Maybe the problem is similar to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910) which means you should check all your dependencies/ build files

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :) Maybe you could write (as an answer) which IDE you work with and what you had to do to solve the problem. Especially if you're working with Android Studio - it is not really well documented, so a good answer here could save other developers lots of time.

Comment: I had this exactly problem and the link solved my problem too. I am still using Eclipse and I had to check the android 6.0 under the export Tab but it didn-t worked till I put it top, as suggested on the linked SO question.

Comment: Don't know how to fix this with Android Studio. Any idea?

Comment: @JanineKroser are you sure the array you are passing has elements? I mean    ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  citiesArrayList );   citiesArrayList  needs to have elements and its size should be >0

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved the problem just setting for all the modules in the project the same SDKCompileVersion. Here it is my complete answer in a similar question

Cheers

[Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter' [Android Studio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014843/could-not-find-class-android-widget-themedspinneradapter-android-studio#answer-36351669)

Answer (score 0):

I faced and win this problem!

In case if you are using AndriodAnnotations here the problem is that I filled the lists in the method `onCreate()`.
I used to get View via `findViewById(R.id...)` and worked with them.

Now, as it turned out during debugging, all Views is not created in `onCreate()` yet!
The problem was solved when I found an annotation `@AfterViews` in the docs, and the method under this annotation now fills all my actions and does initialization of fields.

So, anyway, **check your code on NullPointerException caused by invoking empty view object.**

Answer (score 0):

This may not help everyone, but I was having this issue trying to add a spinner to a PopupWindow.

I updated my compileSdkTarget from 23 to 25, and my support library version to 25.1.0, but it didn't help.

It turned out that changing the spinnerMode to "dialog" worked round the problem:

```
<Spinner
 android:id="@+id/group_spinner"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:spinnerMode="dialog"
/>
```

It doesn't completely fix it of course if you really want a dropdown spinner.

Answer (score -2):

There are several different causes of this problem.
In my case (was trying to sign up to Parse), I got this error trying the app on a tablet.When I switched to an Android phone, I got the error message:

> You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it

So, In my `App.java` class I did this:

```
public class App extends Application {


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "PARSE APPLICATION ID", "PARSE CLIENT KEY");
}
}
```

and then in my manifest, I did this:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
```

That was it.Had nothing to do with `Spinner`