# twitter4j.auth.AccessToken not found error in android

Tags: java, android, twitter4j, android-twitter

Hello I have added twitter4j library in my project but when I am trying to run my program its giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.auth.AccessToken error

```
String token ="88888888888888888888888888888888"; 
     String secret = "8888888888888888888888";
     AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
     Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
     twitter.setOAuthConsumer("888888888", "88888888888888888888");
     twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
     try {
         twitter.updateStatus("i ma app");
     } catch (TwitterException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

manifest file:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.twitter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<!-- So that we can get the account name -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Used to request data from the Google+ APIs in the SignInActivity -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!--  Required if we need to invalidate access tokens -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.twitter.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

Comment: add latest `twitter4j library` becoz older version not contains `twitter4j.auth.AccessToken classes`

Comment: I found the ans all I have to do is add all jar to libs folder

Comment: you are right but here you added the latest .jar files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10860072/1765530  &  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10410281/1765530